# ActiveRecord: perform a validation on method call only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

I'm trying to call validation on an ActiveRecord after a certain method in another Ruby file is called. Is there some way I can tie this into ActiveRecord's validation scheme, i.e.:

`validate :cars_have_wheels?, on: after_cache_reset`

Note: `cars_have_wheels?` is a method located in the ActiveRecord object, `after_cache_reset` is the method in the other file.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried: `model.valid?(:after_cache_reset)`?

Comment: I haven't, but don't you need the `validate` line to tell the `valid?` method what to check for? If that's the case, without an `on:` parameter included, it'll just validate the usual times ActiveRecord likes to do it. I'm specifically trying to validate only when this method is called.

Comment: Could you update your question with more details like when exactly you want this validation to run, what's your expectation etc (ideally with the code and with your attempts so far).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#when-does-validation-happen-questionmark) (Ruby on Rails guides):

5 Conditional Validation
Sometimes it will make sense to validate an object only when a given predicate is satisfied. You can do that by using the :if and :unless options, which can take a symbol, a string, a Proc or an Array. You may use the :if option when you want to specify when the validation should happen. If you want to specify when the validation should not happen, then you may use the :unless option.

5.1 Using a Symbol with :if and :unless
You can associate the :if and :unless options with a symbol corresponding to the name of a method that will get called right before validation happens. This is the most commonly used option.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :card_number, presence: true, if: :paid_with_card?

 def paid_with_card?
  payment_type == "card"
 end
end
```

Comment: This hits it right on the dot. Thank you very much!